# gawk - Trouble with arrays of arrays to catch duplicate strings

Tags: multidimensional-array, duplicates, gawk

I am using gawk 4.1.1 to parse Cisco IOS configuration files, comparing switch configs to the routers above them, to eventually pull out IP addresses. My problem is I need to skip a record (interface) if I have already processed the vlan before. The catch is I am processing multiple files from different sites, and each site has it's own vlans.

So I thought an array of arrays would work best, where array[pop] could be array[den01], array[nyc01], etc. Dynamically creating those index-arrays from the variable pop, pulled from a text file.

The data processing works fine, except that it produces duplicate vlan numbers at a given site. The "dbfile" contains every vlan seen on every switch, from every site, and some people have redundant links so their vlan shows up twice.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat dbfile` ]; do

# set lots of variables to pull into awk

awk -v i=$i -v name=$name -v intname=$intname -v cvupfile=$cvupfile -v pop=$pop -v cid=$cid -v custvlan=$custvlan 'BEGIN { RS="!"; FS=" "; array[pop][0] = "" }
{
if ( $1 ~ "interface" && $2 ~ "Vlan" )
{
    # trim Vlan ID so only the actual vlan number remains
    seenvlan=gensub(/^Vlan/, "", "g", $2)
    if ( seenvlan == custvlan )
    {
        # this is where trouble starts. I never get this IF to be true
        if ( custvlan in array[pop] )
        {
            print "Duplicate VLAN found!"
        }
        else
        {
            # vlan is unique, make index for it
            array[pop][custvlan]=custvlan
            # debug output
            for ( i in array )
                print "This is first element: " i
                for ( j in array[i] )
                    print "This is second element: " array[i][j]
                print "Here is value from array: "  array[pop][custvlan]
                exit
        }
    }
}
}
END {
}' $crt

done
```

Here is some sample output. It shows 3 records processed. The fact that "This is the second element" is printed twice seems like a clue, but I'm not sure what it means. I am making a bunch of null indexes under array[pop]?

```
This is first element: den01
This is second element:
This is second element: 235
Here is value from array: 235
This is first element: den01
This is second element:
This is second element: 279
Here is value from array: 279
This is first element: den01
This is second element:
This is second element: 131
Here is value from array: 131
```

Comment: I understand now why I get two lines with "second element" in it. In my 'BEGIN' statement I declare ' array[pop][0] = ""' which creates that sub-index, and sets the value to null. And it does that every time I read a line from my db file. So it's doing exactly what I'm telling it in other words :)

Comment: I'm also realizing why it never sees duplicates. My bash `for` loop is re-running awk based on each line of the input file. So that array gets created, destroyed, etc, etc, until the input file is exhausted. So I need to totally rewrite how I am handling this data to get what I need.